# Can you stop Death in Swap Sword?

Tags: swap-sword

So, Death, right? He appears so many turns after unlocking the exit. Can you kill/stop him?

- I don't think you can ever swap with him, he always seems to strike first, unlike any other enemy.
- I thought I saw a power that would slow or stop him temporarily.
- I am currently trying to catch him in a dynamite blast, will that kill or stun him?
- How about windmills or ice slides, do either work? Does the latter also result in his first strike and your death?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most enemies cannot move through walls. There is one that can move/attack diagonally, though. You can usually temporarily stop enemies by surrounding yourself with blocks either by spell or matching/moving. However, Death can destroy walls!

**You can stun Death** for one turn by

- hitting him with a dynamite
- hitting him with attack magic

[image]

There is this one-time-use spell, "Remove death for 30 turns."

[image]